# Serializing data with WIRE Akka.net

Tags: c#, serialization, f#, akka

I need to send some Data from  one actor to another over the network. I am using  wire serialization to serialize and deserialize object.
I tried following code to serialize data.

```
val system = ActorSystem("example")

// Get the Serialization Extension
val serialization = SerializationExtension(system)

// Have something to serialize
val original = "woohoo"

// Find the Serializer for it
val serializer = serialization.findSerializerFor(original)

// Turn it into bytes
val bytes = serializer.toBinary(original)
```

How to deserialize respective object on target machine(because we are not having reference of "serializer" on target machine)?